# drupal 6 views broken?

Tags: php, sql, drupal-6, view

Is my drupal 6 views broken?

I have this SQL generated from my view

```
SELECT quiz_node_properties.vid AS vid, quiz_node_properties.nid AS
quiz_node_properties_nid FROM quiz_node_properties quiz_node_properties
```

I expect this output:

```
Quiz Node NID: 6
```

I get this output:

```
Quiz Node NID: 6
Quiz Node NID: 6
Quiz Node NID: 6
Quiz Node NID: 6
```

Why does it quadruple my output? There is only one quiz in my system...

Comment: Why do you not get any results about the vid column? Or are you leaving them out? My suspicion is that you have four revisions of your quiz node saved in the table.

Comment: Ah, sounds reasonable. But I only want the most recent one of course. This is supposed to be the easiest way to list all your quizzes - forgive me but I find it confusing... Do I really have to bash up my own SQL query just to list all nodes av a certain type (quiz)?

Comment: It would be easy to say 'works for me' here and leave it at that. First off, check that your view is of type 'node' and not 'node revision'. If all else fails, a screen shot of the view settings might provide more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I had not chosen to do a view of nodes but of quizzes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the "distinct" option? admin/build/views/ => edit view => Advanced settings => Distinct => yes

Comment: This option is checked (by default) "Display only distinct items, without duplicates."